# Two-Step GMM and Instrumental Variable

Tags: r, econometrics, instrumental-variables, generalized-moments

I am trying to run a regression in r using country-level panel data with female labour force participation rate as the independent variable and lnGDP, lnGDP^2, Trade (as % of GDP), Fertility, School enrollment as the dependent variables. In the paper I am basing my estimation method and mode off of, they use two-step GMM and was concerned about Trade being endogenous so they used trade lagged one year as an instrumental variable. However, I am very unsure about how to use two-step GMM and IVs in r.

- additional question, can you use country-specific dummies to control for unit specific effects with GMM?

Comment: From your description this sounds like regular [2SLS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2sls).